# javax.mail.Message getSentDate returning null

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have come across a case where reading emails from a POP3 inbox using java's mail api returns a null sentDate.

I have gone through the documentation as well as the JavaMail API FAQ and I have yet to find a reason why this could happening.

Has anyone noticed something like that and if yes, what could be causing an email to have a null sent date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Date header is missing from the sent message, you'll get a null sent date.  This has nothing to do with POP3.  Note that POP3 doesn't support a received date so that will always be null.